# Why is the leaves on my tomato plants doing this?

Tags: tomatoes

[image]

Downward curl:I planted 8 tomato plants, 3 varieties and 3 of them developed a downward wonky curl to many of the leaves.  They were fine until a few days ago. Watering daily, raised beds, compost and tomato fertilizer at planting. All other plants in the bed seem to be fine. No pesticides used at all. Neem oil applied in case it was a bug. No sign of pests. I’m afraid of losing them all. I’m a rookie but never had this happen before. Any solutions, answers, suggestions are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: A good rule to follow with pesticides is to never use one unless you have first identified the pest that you want to kill, and then only use a pesticide that will kill that pest. Randomly spraying something on a plant does no good and could, in some cases, harm the plant.

Comment: Haven’t used any pesticides. We used Neem oil on a pepper plant at the other end of the 8’ long bed. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Guess I'm confused by these sentences: "No pesticides used at all. Neem oil applied in case it was a bug." They appear to me to be contradictory, since Neem oil is a pesticide. Unless you meant that you hadn't used any chemical pesticides?

Comment: Correct. I have not used any chemical pesticides on anything. Trying to be as organic as possible. Only used Neem oil on pepper plants at the other end of the 8’ long raised bed at first due to black spots. I did try using the Neem oil on the tomato after this started to prevent any bug that may be causing this as I was told Neem oil is fine on tomato plants.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like herbicide vapor drift to me.  It happened to me several times before I finally started covering my plants with blankets when spraying my lawn.  Do you have neighbors that could have sprayed weed killer?  Tomato plants don't need droplets; just vapor will do it.  After a month or more, I have seen the plants recover, but that is a long time.

Comment: Dana, look at the answer to this question: https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/41626/tomato-plant-after-neem-oil-application. It pertains to the soap used with the Neem oil - if you used the wrong soap, then you can actually damage the tomato. This would then be consistent with @Evil Elf 's answer of chemical drift.